# SQLAlchemy/Pandas: Can not insert default time in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I create a table using sqlalchemy, and I want to set a default timestamp in mysql, but it can not insert into mysql, my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Float, ForeignKey,TIMESTAMP

Base = declarative_base()
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    bid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bname = Column(String(20))
    price = Column(Integer)

    student_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Student.id))

    student = relationship(Student)
    insert_time = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=False),
                         default=datetime.datetime.now())

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
books = pd.DataFrame({"bname": ['a','b','c','d'],
                      "price":[128,22,67,190],
                      'student_id':[1,1,3,2]})
books.to_sql('book',engine,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

look at the book table, the `insert_time` field is `null`, not the datetime, how I deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using SQLAlchemy you should strive to understand what takes place in Python and what in the database. Here you have defined a default value for `insert_time` using the [`default`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default) argument, compared to using [`server_default`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default), so the default value is added to the values *in Python*, if no value for the column was specified, and only if you are using either the specified model or underlying `Table`.

If you created the table based on the model you have shown, then there is no server side default value and the column is nullable. This matters, because Pandas does a bulk insert using its own metadata, so it does not know about your Python side default.

In MySQL – depending on version and flags – a column of type `TIMESTAMP` is implicitly `NOT NULL` unlike any other type and the first timestamp column has a server side default of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but [SQLAlchemy emits the `NULL` specifier explicitly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#timestamp-columns-and-null) if `nullable=False` is not specified, in order to make the behaviour consistent with other DBMS.

Finally, you most probably meant to pass the function `datetime.datetime.now` as the default, not an instance of `datetime` that you get during class construction when you call the function:

```
    insert_time = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=False),
                         default=datetime.datetime.now)  # Don't call it, pass it
```

You should also explicitly specify a server side default, if using Pandas as you have shown:

```
    # Having `default` as well is a bit redundant.
    insert_time = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=False),
                         default=datetime.datetime.now,
                         server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
                         nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datetime instance of TIMESTAMP

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Float, ForeignKey,DateTime

Base = declarative_base()
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    bid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bname = Column(String(20))
    price = Column(Integer)

    student_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Student.id))

    student = relationship(Student)
    insert_time = Column(Datetime,
                         default=datetime.datetime.now())

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
books = pd.DataFrame({"bname": ['a','b','c','d'],
                      "price":[128,22,67,190],
                      'student_id':[1,1,3,2]})
books.to_sql('book',engine,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

Comment: The column's still nullable though, and the (static) default is not used in pandas.